# Could gravitational wave permanently distort a region of spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, gravitational-waves

Imagine a flat spacetime being disturbed by a gravitational wave from a very distant source, say given enough time would that flat spacetime recovers meaning it must be at the same state as before, flat? Please assume a static universe because I simply want to know how spacetime works beside just time dilation.

Comment: Different but similar, is the notion that gravitational waves might becomes self bound soliton-like objects behaving as though massive. https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.56.4824 Most recent paper I could find

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If you think of spacetime as a fabric, and a huge mass (such as a blackhole) as a marble, then as soon as you lift the marble then the fabric changes back into its original curvature, which is zero (Or at least think based on our current observations). In addition, based on LIGO's observations, astronomers have created 3-D models to depict black hole collisions and mergers, and the indentation of spacetime follows the motion of the black holes.

Comment: You're trying to take a mathematical model too literally. Calling spacetime a "fabric" is just a nice way of making the concept of relativity accessible to those who aren't physicists. It is not literally a fabric but that word is used to explain it in terms of something we are more familiar with.